# entered the room extending my hand

Tags: punctuation, participles

a. I entered the room extending my hand to my host.

c. He forgot his wallet in the restaurant realizing it two hours later.

d. He forgot his wallet in the restaurant, realizing it two hours later.

e. She entered the room weeping.

f. She entered the room, weeping.

Do the above sentences work?

Are the commas needed?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is certain a duplicate, but I can't pick which of maybe two dozen would be the best to list.  (Hint:  Look at the "RELATED" column to your right.)

Comment: I'll just comment on _e_ and _f_. They are both grammatical and idiomatic, but they have different thrusts. In _e_, the 'weeping' is essentially a subject-orientated depictive adjective and intimately connected with the referent. Compare 'He went home happy'. In _f_, there is far more of a two-statement feel: 'She entered the room. She was weeping.'